# React/TypeScript error: Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is my LoginContainer.ts Not sure why I'm getting these typescript errors in my render method:

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Actions
// import { addCoins } from 'actions/coins';

interface IProps {
  loginActions: any
}

interface IState {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

class LoginContainer extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

  public state: IState = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  public render() {
    return (
      <div id="login-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
//   addCoins: (...args) => dispatch(addCoins(...args))
// });

export const LoginContainerJest = LoginContainer;

export default connect(null, null)(LoginContainer);
```

Comment: You have JSX in this file so the extension for typescript should be `.tsx`, so try renaming the file to `LoginContainer.tsx`.

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah that removed that error, but now I'm getting a `property` error on the markup. If you want to post this answer I'll go ahead and create a new question for the other error.

Comment: @CRice if you have a moment :) also you want to post the answer? +1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322802/jsx-error-property-does-not-exist-on-type-jsx-intrinsicelements

Comment: Glad to help. Looks like you already figured out the other issue .

Comment: Keeping this open as it's a common issue, regardless of typo.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Typescript supports JSX syntax but requires a different extension `.tsx`. Renaming your file to `LoginContainer.tsx` should allow typescript to interpret the syntax properly.

[From the typescript handbook:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

> In order to use JSX you must do two things.
>
> 1. Name your files with a .tsx extension
> 2. Enable the jsx option (in your tsconfig file)